# TypeError: 'Label' object not callable

Tags: python, data-binding, typeerror

I am creating a simple python GUI, which uses labels to bind a gif image to a function. However, it returns the error `TypeError: 'Label' object not callable`

The code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
mode = 'draw'
filename = PhotoImage(file = 'bin\\Images\\pencil.gif')
draw = Label(tk, image=filename, width=53, height=47)
draw.place(x = 60, y = 620)
draw.img = filename
draw.bind('<Double-Button-1>', draw)
filename = PhotoImage(file = 'bin\\Images\\select.gif')
select = Label(tk, image=filename, width=53, height=46)
select.place(x = 160, y = 620)
select.img = filename
select.bind('<Double-Button-1>', select)
filename = PhotoImage(file = 'bin\\Images\\select_all.gif')
select_all = Label(tk, image=filename, width=53, height=48)
select_all.place(x = 260, y = 620)
select_all.img = filename
select_all.bind('<Double-Button-1>', select_all)
filename = PhotoImage(file = 'bin\\Images\\delete.gif')
delete = Label(tk, image=filename, width=50, height=45)
delete.place(x = 360, y = 620)
delete.img = filename
delete.bind('<Double-Button-1>', delete)
filename = PhotoImage(file = 'bin\\Images\\instrument_choose.gif')
inst = Label(tk, image=filename, width=355, height=51)
inst.place(x = 700, y = 620)
inst.img = filename
inst.bind('<Double-Button-1>', draw)
```

There is no line number shown in the traceback reading as a line from my file. The functions don't have any parameters, and what they do is continue to the next line so far.

Comment: `draw.bind('<Double-Button-1>', draw)` , draw is not a function

Comment: `select_all.bind('<Double-Button-1>', select_all)` same with `select_all` and `select`

Comment: @rdas I removed the functions from the code mentioned. I said that they had no parameters, and they just continue to the next line.

Comment: @Mitchel_Paulin  I removed the functions from the code mentioned. I said that they had no parameters, and they just continue to the next line.

Comment: `draw = Label(tk, image=filename, width=53, height=47)` defines `draw` to be a `Label` instance. `draw.bind('<Double-Button-1>', draw)` bind the button to this `Label`, but they are not callable. You then repeat this error several more times.